# Latex-workshop plugin on vscode doesn't display pdf suddenly

Tags: pdftex, pdf

The latex-workshop plugin on vscode worked flawlessly until it abruptly stopped displaying pdfs in the environment, and shows this instead:

[image]

Trying to open a pdf via a File->Open used to work earlier but now throws up an error as follows:

[image]

I'm using WSL-2 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Due to a bug of VS Code >= 1.47.0. See https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/2206

Answer (score 0):

when this happen to me i just reboot the virtual machine of wsl just like this:

```
$> wsl --shutdown
```

This command above shutdown all distros in you machine. Or you can just eject with this other one:

```
$> wsl --terminate <Dist>
```

If you want know the correct name of your distros, run this one:

```
$> wsl --list -v
```

The output saw like this:

```
     NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-20.04      Running             2
```

The Distro marked with a asterisk is the distro by default, also you can saw the version of this and it current estate.

After this, you only just re-call to wsl command and this launch the distro marked as default.

Try again view the preview of your document (you know; ctl+alt+v).

If after all you can't see anything, you must verify if any other application is using some port that latex-workshop needs.